# Google OAuth2 and Service Accounts in .net

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-api, gdata

I am trying to figure out how to read contacts from Google Contacts with OAuth 2.

I am using C# and writing a .NET windows application.

I have an application that has worked until a few days ago, but now Google has deactivated OAuth 1, and I can't understand how to use OAuth 2.

I have this situation:

- Google Service Account: this generated a Client ID, an email address and a P12 private key;
- Google users: previously I used directly user name and password of each user to access its contacts, now it does not work anymore;
- The users can be normal users or Google Domain users;
- The application doesn't interact with the user, it is a service application that reads contacts from the specified Google account and imports in my application.

I use ContactsQuery and ContactsService to read contacts.
Previosly I used this code to create the ContactsService:

```
ContactsService service = new ContactsService("MyApp");
service.setUserCredentials("nameofaccount@gmail.com","password");
```

What do I have to modify to use the new OAuth 2 Service Account credentials?

I tried to look at the Google documentation, but now I am even more confused..

Comment: your going to have to try and see if you can add the service account email address as a user that has access to the Google domain contacts.

Comment: and if the user is not a Google Domain user? the application should work on any type of accounts...

Comment: A service account only gives you access to data you as the developer own.    If you want access to a users contacts you have to use Oauth2 and request authentication from your users.

Comment: Thank you DalmTo, you pointed me in the right direction, I thought that I could access without asking the user to open his browser, but I was wrong, I have to create an "Installed application" project and show to the user the google page to require the access and refresh tokens, and use the second when the access token expires